# Reload a DIV that includes DB value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have three different files **helper.php**, **scripts.php** and **profile.php**. Into **profile.php** I have a **DIV** that shows user's points `<div id="content"><?php echo $points ?></div>`. It takes variables from **helper.php** where I have all my DB queries. I want only this **DIV** to reload every 10 seconds or when user click on reload button.

So fisrt I tried to make it reload every 10 seconds. I found a script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $JQ = jQuery.noConflict();

function Reload_Content(){
$JQ('#content').load('index.php').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);}

setInterval('Reload_Content()', 10000);
</script>
```

This script, as it is now, every 10 seconds reloads my whole index.php and not only the DIV that contains user's points!

Any idea how can I make it work? Thank you in advance!

**PS:** I am really new in JQuery!!!

Comment: Do it through Ajax. on SetTimeOut function call a function every 10 section which calculate points for you and update the div.

Comment: @GreenMadness send ajax request to that page and get points..after that change inner html of that div..
if you say i will do it for you... :)

Comment: My friend **saqlain786** can you please give me an example?

Comment: @MShahzadKhan: Any example my friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use the REST method provided by Ben. However if you are set on using load you can filter the HTML it returns using the elements ID.

```
$("#content").load("index.php #content");
```

The whole index.php would still be loaded so it is not as efficient as using JSON to only sent the number of points.

Comment: I did as your example and it's working now!!! But I have a question... As the script is now, it loads the whole **index.php** everytime and shows only `#content` DIV? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't see someone to give better or more helpful answer than yours so I'll check yours as correct for now... Just on more question. What is the syntax if I want all this happens using a button?

Comment: If you want this to happen on a button/link click just bind the event to the execution of your function. `$(document).on('click', '#button_ID', function(){ Reload_Content(); });`

Answer (score 0):

you can only run a php code using reloding  the hole page
other wise use ajax xmlrequest and javascript

or simply you can  use the jquery ajax function for the index.php and show it in that div

Comment: $.ajax({
   url: "login.php",
   success: function(data){
     $("#content").html(data);
   }
 });

Answer (score 0):

a highly sophisticated way would be to create a REST web-service which provides valid JSON and let jQuery fetch those at a resource like http://anyhost.com/REST/points/user/JoeBud/. 
Tbh it's not that hard to learn.

another way would be to preserve the user_id in the session variable and create a dedicated points.php file which retrieves the user_id out of the session and performs a db query.
This file could be implemented using your setTimeOut-approach

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AJAX if you want to do this properly. First you'll need an endpoint that returns the number of points in JSON. For example:

```
$points = 50; // Retrieve your points before here.

echo json_encode(array(
  'points' => $points
));

// This will return: {points: 50}
```

Then name this `points-api.php` or whatever floats your boat, then you can just use this script to retrieve the points every few seconds:

```
var refresh_points = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "/points-api.php",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#points-div').html(data.points);
    }
  });
}

setInterval(refresh_points, 10000);
```

Comment: function refresh_points() - the call in setInterval is setInterval("refresh_points()", 10000);

Comment: Okay I did correct your example... In my console I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return document.id(a,b,this.document);} has no method 'ajax' index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=2:1949
refresh_points index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=2:1949
(anonymous function)` Do you have any idea what is this?

Comment: Make sure it's `$.ajax` -> Remember the dot. Also: `var refresh_points = function() { ` works the same.r

Comment: Woops, sorry didn't realise the typo on my part there, thanks! :)

Comment: I am getting this all the time... `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return document.id(a,b,this.document);} has no method 'ajax'`

Comment: It's a function called `$.ajax` in jQuery. Make sure your jQuery is up  to date